# Парсинг JSON-файла

Tags: json, golang

Есть JSON-файл, автоматически сгенерированный программой на Go:

```
{
    "StatusS8":"2018-08-09",
    "StatusS9E202":"2018-08-09",
    "StatusS9E203":"2018-08-09",
    "StatusS10E207":"2018-08-09",
    "TimeS8":"2018-08-09",
    "TimeS9E202":"2018-08-09",
    "TimeS9E203":"2018-08-09",
    "TimeS10E207":"2018-08-09"
}
```

Необходимо прочесть данный файл и потом распарсить в структуру `DateSend`.

Структура `DateSend`:

```
type DateSend struct {
    StatusS8      string
    StatusS9E202  string
    StatusS9E203  string
    StatusS10E207 string

    TimeS8      string
    TimeS9E202  string
    TimeS9E203  string
    TimeS10E207 string
}
```

Функция, в которой идет чтение и парсинг:

```
func JSONRead() (date DateSend) {
    defer Completion("JsonRead")
    defer log.Print("1: ", date.StatusS8)

    file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/zahp/" + nameDir + "/" + nameDateFile)
    //os.Stdout.Write(file)
    json.Unmarshal(file, &date)
    return date
}
```

Данные в переменную `file` считываются верно, но в `date` ничего не записывается.

P.S. Код без обработки ошибок, так как на данный момент нужен результат.

Comment: Надо передавать `&date`, иначе у вас ничего не декодится.Что за паника? В этом коде паники быть не должно.

Comment: да паники нет, но все равно не парсится

Comment: В ответе не то написал, удалил. Можете сделать воспроизводимый пример и выложить на https://play.golang.org?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/sn8KGgLcYQS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аргументы `defer` вычисляются там, где вы используете `defer`. В вашем случае `defer` будет вызываться с пустой строкой. Если вы переместите лог после декодинга, всё работает:

```
json.Unmarshal(file, &date)
log.Print("1: ", date.StatusS8)
```

Видим:

```
2018/09/21 13:00:31 1: 2018-08-09
```

Comment: Поменял на `//os.Stdout.Write(file)
 err = json.Unmarshal(file, &date)`
Результат тот же, т.е никакой

Comment: @Geo Вроде, починил.

Comment: Спасибо, впредь буду знать